# how to reload language files in "production"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n

How to reload language files in Production?

```
I18n.backend.reload!
```

This method doesn't work.

(trying to reload via url, attached to this action)

Comment: This approach seems a little bit risky. When your server runs multiple instances of you app, how will you ensure each instance reloads the language files?

Comment: Agree with you. This approach only for one instance app.

Comment: We solved this problem by fetching all hostnames for the instances. And build simple API for reloading locales. Implementation see in comment below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reload language files without reloading application server using:

```
I18n.backend.load_translations
```

Comment: This saved me. Thank you!